# Disable OmniAuth's Email Case-Sensitivity?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using OmniAuth for user registration (Facebook and Identity), but I'd like to disable the default case sensitivity. I've added .downcase! to the user creation, so that's taken care of insert fields into the 'User' table - but my identities table can still contain camelcase nonsense. Has anyone dealt with this before, and if so, how?

Comment: No solutions provided so here's a potential workaround. If your existing camelCasedEmails bother you, and you already ensured their lowercasing for the future then you might consider performing an update query like `User.update_all('email = LOWER(email)')`.

Comment: Thanks jdoe, but what I'm looking for is a way to make omniauth ignore case when logging a user in. Users use their email address to log in, and omni is being a pain about case sensitivity.